# Magento 2: Change text Upsell in Magento2 Product Edit

Tags: magento2, admin, up-sells

How to Change Up-Sell text in Product Edit from admin(Products -> Catalog-> Edit) in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text `"Up-Sell Products"` is present inside the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php` line `341`. If you open the file you will notice that the text is enclosed with a `__('Up-Sell Products')` which means its multi-locale ready.

So you can simply use the `i18n\en_US.csv` file inside your custom theme or a custom module to change the text from `"Up-Sell Products"` to whatever you want.

Reference file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv` line `438`.

This way is much simpler and doesn't require any kind of module overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, You need to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php`

and change `Up-sell`  to any other.

**di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related" type="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related" />
</config>
```

create `Related.php` into following  file `vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;`

Copy and Paste `Related.php` form `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php`

And change UP-sell Related text to what ever you want.

Clear Cache, and Check it. let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: HI while adding up-sells from admin getting error on popup (something went be wrong ), can you please

Comment: @suresh-vagvala  you got any logs and you only changed label name not a functionality, check you recently changed functions.